# Observer checkout success - change customer group switch country

Tags: checkout, event-observer, customer, customer-group

Is this possible to get customer country (or country code) in checkout success observer ?
I would like to create a custom module (it's okay) to change customer ID switch his country after he orders.

Is this possible to get customer country in my Observer.php ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write below code in config.xml 
File: app/code/local/Letsknowit/Postdata/Checkout/etc/config.xml

```
   <config>
        <global>
           <models>
             <postdata>
                <class>Letsknowit_Postdata_Model</class>
              </postdata>
           </models>
        <events>
          <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
           <observers>
             <postDataTosServer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>Letsknowit_Postdata_Model_Checkout_Observer</class>
                  <method>postDataTosServer</method>
            </postDataTosServer>
          </observers>
         </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
      </events>    
   </global>   
 </config>
```

You need to write below code in Observer

File: app/code/local/Letsknowit/Postdata/Model/Checkout/Observer.php

```
<?php 
class Letsknowit_Postdata_Model_Checkout_Observer 
{
     public function postDataTosServer(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        $orderIds = $observer->getData('order_ids');
         foreach($orderIds as $_orderId){
            $order     = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($_orderId);
            $customer  = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getData('customer_id'));
            $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getLastname();
           $billingaddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
           $countryCode = $billingaddress->getData('country_id');
           /* update and save user contry id */
           $countryId = 1 ;// put here desired country id
           $customer->setCountryId($countryId);
           $customer->save();




     }
 }   

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `sales_order_place_after` event then you will be able to get all the details of custom after he places the order. Here you can change the customer Id and all the things you want to change.

If you want it before placing the order then try `sales_order_place_before`.

I think it might be helpful for you.